# Why is this script changing my file's ctime?

Tags: php, macos, md5, stat, ctime

I'm writing a forensic disk catalogue script in PHP. The script iterates over a filesystem, gathers various metadata and statistical information about each file or directory, and stores that information in a SQL database. It is critical for my application that the filesystem remain unaltered to whatever extent possible. Mounting the filesystem read-only is an option, but not a good one.

The issue I'm having is that something in my script is modifying the files' ctimes. Running stat against the file before and after the script shows the ctime has changed to the execution time of the script. I understand and expect the atimes to be modified, and have had success caching the atime, reading the file, and writing the original atime back afterwards. But ctimes cannot be modified arbitrarily without extraordinary effort.

Here are the relevant commands that are run against each file. Note this is a Mac system and there are some Mac specific commands:

```
#get stat
stat -x $path

#directory item count excluding dotfiles
find $path \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) | wc -l

#get size
du -ks $path

#get HFS+ attrs (Mac)
GetFileInfo -P $path

#get quicklook thumbnail (Mac)
qlmanage -t -f 2 -o /tmp/thumb.jpg $path

#get media thumbnail
ffmpegthumbnailer -i $path -o /tmp/ -s 200 -c png 

#get spotlight metadata (Mac)
mdls -plist - $path

#get mediainfo
mediainfo --Output=XML $path

#get exif
exiftool -php $path
```

Additionally, many of PHP's built-in file methods are used:

```
$splFileInfo->getSize();
$splFileInfo->getLinkTarget();
$splFileInfo->getRealPath();
$splFileInfo->getInode();
$splFileInfo->getPerms();
$splFileInfo->getOwner();
$splFileInfo->getGroup();
$splFileInfo->getCTime();
$splFileInfo->getMTime();
```

I am also generating a hash:

```
md5_file($path);
```

Is there a kind soul out there who can see anything in this list that could conceivably modify a file's ctime? From what I understand, the ctime should change only when a file or a file's metadata is altered. None of these commands should do that.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should quote your variables. Otherwise, the script won't work correctly for filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: Try putting `stat -f %c "$file"` after each command, to see which one is doing it.

Comment: I tried your script on one of my files, it didn't change the ctime. I don't have a the `mediainfo` or `exiftool` commands, though.

Comment: Yes in the script the shell paths are encapsulated properly. I did try each command one by one and none seem to do it, but the script does. I'm thinking it might be the PHP methods but that makes even less sense!

Comment: If none of the commands in the script do it, then it's not happening in this script. It must be in the code that's getting the filenames and calling the script.

Comment: Here's the code that iterates over the input directory. I can't see how this would modify anything. I've tried commenting out the shell commands, and the files are not modified. I don't get it... https://pastebin.com/raw/9iBQxige

Comment: Where is the code that runs the shell script?

Comment: There is no shell script, these commands are called from a PHP script using shell_exec. You want to see the whole PHP script?

Comment: I think we're going to have to. Otherwise I'm just speculating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146916/discussion-between-utt50-and-barmar).